# Selective sync of iCloud drive

Tags: macos, icloud, data-synchronization

I would like to switch from Dropbox to iCloud drive and wanted to know if there is any way to select specific folders which are going to be downloaded on my Mac? It is possible in Dropbox client.
There are some folders that I would like to have in the cloud but not taking space on my local Mac.

Comment: I have the same issue. Seems it's not possible.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is selective sync possible with iCloud?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/372063/is-selective-sync-possible-with-icloud)

Comment: yes, it does but I think the other question was a duplicate of mine.