# Is selective sync possible with iCloud?

Tags: icloud

So i have one iCloud account and two Macbooks : one mac for work, another for personal use.

I want to use iCloud as cloud backup on both Macbooks, BUT i don't want one Mac to download content of another.

For instance, in work's Mac i have a folder with almost 100GB, that is useless for me on personal Mac. And still, this folder is being downloaded on my personal Mac, making me loose 100GB for nothing.

On Dropbox i had the Selective sync option, where i could select which folders would be synced. But i could not find something similar on Icloud.

Is this possible in iCloud ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

macOS Catalina (10.15) includes new functionalities that allow selective sync on iCloud. In the context menu, accessible by right clicking on a file / folder in iCloud, there are two new options:

- **Remove Download:** the selected item(s) will be removed from your device, while remaining in iCloud.
- **Download Now:** download previously removed files from iCloud.