# Folder in iCloud that stores files only in cloud but doesn't sync with Mac

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, icloud, storage

I'm new to the ecosystem with my new MacBook Pro and I have a question about iCloud storage. I don't have a large SSD so I hope to use my iCloud for files, that's why I subscribed to some storage too. However now I see that all my files that are in cloud are also on my Mac. Some of them I need but my question is wheter it is possible to create a folder in the iCloud that uploads the files and then remove them from the computer?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is selective sync possible with iCloud?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/372063/is-selective-sync-possible-with-icloud)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is possible to manage this - basically you have two options:

**1)** Let macOS handle this automatically

You enable this from **System Preferences** by clicking **Apple ID**, **iCloud** and then ensure that **Optimise Mac Storage** is checked.

This ensures that everything is stored in iCloud Drive, and as much as possible is also stored on the Mac. However as available space becomes low, the system might delete files from the Mac so that they're only stored in iCloud.

In this case you have no control over which files and folders macOS keeps on the computer and which are only available in iCloud.

**2)** Handle it manually yourself

In the Finder open iCloud and right-click the folder and select **Remove Download**. This removes the folder's contents on your Mac, but keeps it in iCloud Drive.