# iCloud 'Remove download' feature

Tags: icloud, finder, mojave

I'm trying to free up some room on my hard drive and store it on iCloud as online-only.

According to the following answer, there is a 'remove download' option when right-clicking on any iCloud files / folders in Finder:

[Folder in iCloud that stores files only in cloud but doesn't sync with Mac](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/404440/folder-in-icloud-that-stores-files-only-in-cloud-but-doesnt-sync-with-mac)

I can't see this option when I right-click, see attached screengrab at the bottom.

Bear in mind I'm running Mojave 10.14.6 — is this a new feature in iCloud?

Comment: Linked from your link, it was new in Catalina - https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/372063/is-selective-sync-possible-with-icloud Up until then iCloud is *purely* a sync solution, not a backup solution.  It's still best to think of it in this way.